# Get Output Equations for a LSTM Model Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, output, lstm, equation

I have an LSTM model (combined with fully connected layers) built like this. Is there any function or is there any way to get the equations of the model that shows us the relation between the input and the final output??

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units = 120, activation ='relu', return_sequences = True,input_shape =(train_in.shape[1],5)))
     
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I need to use the equations of the model for a different purpose. So, please let me know if there is any built in function available for this.

Thank You :)

Comment: what kind of relation are you talking about

Comment: there is no way to get the mathematical formula of your model, however, you can do it manually. I have done a few times. It is a game of patience but possible. Use tensorboard to get the whole graph and go from there.  Remove your dropout layers, of course, because they don't make sense for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello @CrazyBrazzilian, Yes, I want to know how to do them manually. I have that patience :D .. please share any reference to the manual method you used. And here when I use the 'model.get_weights()', I can only see 2 weight matrices of (5,480) & (120,480) dimension and one bias matrix of 480 dimension for the above model mentioned(edited). So I want to know what are those weights and how do I frame equations of LSTM with that weights. As LSTM has 4 layers and I declared 120 units, can I assume that the 1st 120 values correspond to the 1st layer and next 120 to the 2nd layer and so on?

Answer (score 1):

LSTM equation looking like that (every LSTM layer):

[image]

see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory

Dense layer equations are:

y = activation(W * x + b)

Dropout layers don't add any equation.

Comment: Hello @Andrey, I know about the equations you have mentioned above. But when I use the 'model.get_weights()' function, I can only see 2 weight matrices of (5,480) & (120,480) dimension and one bias matrix of 480 dimension for the above model mentioned(edited). So I want to know what are those weights and how do I frame equations of LSTM with that weights and biases